How can you find the minimum number of intersection points a graph can be drawn with, given a specific graph?
For those of you who don't know, a graph in math is a set of point, typically referred to as nodes, connected by lines, typically referred to as edges. For this particular problem, all the points will be colored the same color (I'm uncertain whether or not that matters to the problem though). A planar graph is a graph that can be drawn such that no 2 edges intersect (the edges are allowed to be curves and are not necessarily straight lines).
I'm well aware that there is a certain formula which can be applied to tell whether a graph is planar or not, but how can you tell what the minimum number of intersection points is? Of
course, you could simply try every single possible configuration of the graph, but how can you tell that there isn't a configuration that you missed? How can you prove that you really have tried every single one?
If there is a way to prove that you have tried every single configuration, is there a more efficient algorithm somewhere out there?

Do you have a specific graph in mind? As noted in Bruno's answer, this is generally a hard problem.

I was thinking in general, but I'd be happy to hear the answers for specific types of graphs too.

This is generally very hard, even for relatively natural families of graphs (like complete graphs and complete bipartites, there are conjectures but they remain unproven, see here and here). The crossing number (i.e. the minimum possible number of edge crossings in a planar drawing) is known for a few family of graphs; but in general you have no standard method, though bounds are known. Particular upper bounds for particular families, like the ones given in the links above exist, but also lower bounds, such as the crossing number inequality which is many times enough to solve many problems
